# Multiplicative inverse of $2^{n}\textrm{ mod }v $

Tags: number-theory

This just came up in my research. It's probably one of those hopeless, apparently-random number-theoretic phenomena that will puzzle mankind for all time, but I thought I might as well ask.

Let $n$ be a non-negative integer, and $v$ be an odd integer $\geq3$. Define $M\left(n,v\right)$ as the multiplicative inverse of $2^{n}\textrm{ mod }v$. Are there any explicitly statable properties of $M\left(n,v\right)$
  as $v$
  and $n$
  vary? (Specific values / formulae, asymptotic growth estimates, trends in histograms; anything at all, really). In particular, what can be said of $M\left(n,v\right)$
  for fixed $n$
  as $v$
  varies?

All I can find is that: 
$$M\left(0,v\right) = 1$$
$$M\left(1,v\right) = \frac{v+1}{2}$$
 It gets weird for $n\geq2$:
$$M\left(2,v\right) = 1,4,2,7,3,10,4,13,5,16,...$$
$$M\left(3,v\right) = 2,2,1,8,7,5,2,15,12,8,...$$
$$M\left(4,v\right) = 1,1,4,4,9,9,1,16,6,4,...$$
$$M\left(5,v\right) = 2,3,2,2,10,11,8,8,3,2,...$$

Comment: if v=3 we get that $$2^n\equiv -1^n \pmod 3$$ which explains the first value in each n value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By [Euler's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_theorem), assuming that $v$ is odd, we know that $$2^{\phi(v)}\equiv 1\pmod{v}$$
Hence, $2^{\phi(v)-1}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2$, modulo $v$. Here $\phi(v)$ denotes the Euler [totient](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euler%27s_totient_function).

More generally, $2^{\phi(v)-n}$ is the multiplicative inverse of $2^n$, modulo $v$, for $1\le n\le \phi(v)$.  In OP's notation, $$M(n,v)=2^{\phi(v)-n}$$

Comment: Marvelous! Thank you!